# Excel;VBA Array Loading Time

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Below is a code I use to fill an array with items, the array is "public declared"

```
lastrow = DataBase.Range("a3").End(xlDown).row
lastcolum = DataBase.Range("a1").End(xlToRight).Column

ReDim mainDataBase(lastrow - 2, lastcolum - 1)
For i = 2 To lastrow
    For t = 0 To lastcolum - 1
     mainDataBase(i - 2, t) = DataBase.Cells(i, t + 1).value
    Next t
     
    
Next i

For i = LBound(mainDataBase, 1) To UBound(mainDataBase, 1)
diet.TempCombo.AddItem (mainDataBase(i, 0))
Next i
```

Every time I stop the code and reinitialize the array in such way that no item is accessible it take increasingly more time to fill when I reinitialize the code, see the log ....0s,1s,12s,23s,28s,35s,39s,40s

Why it happens and how can I correct this?

Comment: Referencing cells inside a loop is very slow.  This has been discussed countless times on stack Overflow, and so has the solution: assign your range to a range variable, declare a Variant variable, assign the range.value to the Variant in one step (eg `YourVariant = YourRange.Value2`).  Note that this will be a 1 based array, so your logic will need to be updated to account for that.

Comment: You never clear `diet.TempCombo` so you're just adding more and more items?

Comment: actually no.. the diet.TempCombo is being cleared every time, sorry... I just forgot to include that in the code above

Comment: chris neilsen, yes, that's much faster, but I'm wondering in this post why the array "increases" the time to load when the code is restarted